# Pronunciation Feedback Required

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

Did I pronounce the phrase "I'm gonna be gone for five weeks" correctly? https://clyp.it/oobrogbu

Phonetically it looks like: [aɪm gɑnə bɪ gɔn fər faɪv wiks]. I have no idea which words should I stress, I heard the phrase on the web and tried to imitate it. I think the stress should look like this: [aɪm ˌgɑnə bɪ ˈgɔn fər ˈfaɪv ˌwiks]. I may be wrong. I mean the phrase in a general context, when I want someone to know that I will be gone.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/ might be a more appropriate place for this kind of question.

Comment: Everything's fine in the transcription, except that (in American English, anyway) _gonna_ is pronounced /'ɡənə/, with a stressed shwa (phonetically [∧]), rather than with [ɑ].

Comment: Thanks Digital Chris. Your time is appreciated. Can I remove the question? I don't find the option.

Comment: @John Lawler, could you explain why you added "(phonetically [ʌ])"?  I get the stressed shwa, which is also now normal in British English 'gonna' and 'because'.

Comment: According to Beverly Lujan's book "The American Accent Guide" the [ʌ] is stressed schwa. Some people say both [ʌ] and [ə] are the same sound, although I can hear a difference between them. I'm Hungarian and [ʌ] sounds more like ɑ as in father for me, this is why I used [ɑ] instead of [ʌ]. Anyway I read that Americans don't really make difference between the two sounds.

Comment: Thank-you, Zoltan, that makes sense.  As it happens, I've noticed that here in Northern England, people whose speech is a compromise between their northern accent and RP English tend to use /ə/ for 'short U'.  E.g. pronouncing 'cup' as /kəp/, which in Northern England would be /kʊp/ but in RP /kʌp/.

Comment: I'd say [wiːks] and not [wiks]

Comment: Some Americans use the same vowel for /ʌ/ and /ə/, but some don't.

Comment: It kinda sounds like you said "week" instead of "weeks", though that may be a problem with the recording.   Other than that, an accent is clearly present, but not very strong.

Comment: It's really good. And I can clearly hear the -s ending on *weeks*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a native speaker of American English. I would say that the short o in gone is a tad too short. *Gone* sounded more like *gun* to me. I didn't hear the -v- in *five* or the  -s- in *weeks*, though. As far as the intonation is concerned, which word is the new information? If it's the fact that you're going to be gone, then *gone* is stressed. If it's how long you're going to be gone, then it's *five*. If the listener thought you were going to be gone for five months, then *weeks* is stressed. I the listener thought that someone else was going to be gone, then *I'm* is stressed. You can't really say which intonation is correct without knowing the context, but it did sound natural.

But please, watch out for mistakes like this: *I have no idea which words should I stress*. Embedded questions use statement word order: *I have no idea which words I should stress*.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds fine, just work on the word five. It sounds like you only stressed the fi, but it is important to not forget about the ve

Answer (score 0):

That is a good, neutral emphasis. However, depending on the context of this statement, you could put emphasis in other places.

If you want to convey that five weeks is a long time, you would put the emphasis more strongly and more equally on "five" and "weeks"

Answer (score 0):

Overall accurate.  Your weakest word is "five" which lacks a complete 'v' sound.  Try pronouncing it with two syllables "fi-ve" first, and then turning that word into a single syllable.

Others have mentioned this, but it bears clarification.  Like individual words, a complete sentence will have emphasis placed somewhere.  As this stands, it sounds as though a computer has composed the sentence: phonetically correct, emphatically vague.  Without the context of the question or situation this statement addresses, it is impossible to state where the emphasis will be.

As a native speaker of another language though, analyze how you say this phrase in that language.  Which facets of the sentence to you emphasize then?  Those will likely be the right ones to emphasize here.